# Use Core Telephony For Universal Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-telephony

My Application is using Core Telephony Framework.My application is a universal app and supports both Ipad and Iphone.I tested on Verizon Ipad and I was able to get the carrier using Core Telephony.How should I deal with core telephony on  Ipad devices only with Wifi.Will core telephony class returns NULL on ipad with Wifi or is it going to crash my application on those devices.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *currentCountry=[carrier isoCountryCode];
[networkInfo release];
```

I use this and it works fine on Verizon Ipad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran the code for you, and it doesn't crash.

This is the dump of the CTCarrier

```
TCarrier (0x1f2330) {
    Carrier name: []
    Mobile Country Code: []
    Mobile Network Code:[]
    ISO Country Code:[]
    Allows VOIP? [YES]
}
```